# Symfony3 - How to render Embedded collection of Forms

Tags: symfony, collections, twig, display, symfony3.x

I haven´t found the solution to manually render a form which contains a collection.
Here is my code in twig:

```
<ul id="document-fields-list" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(formulario.documentos.vars.prototype)|e }}">
    <div><button class="pull-right" href="#" id="add-another-document">Agregar documento</button></div>
    {% for documento in formulario.documentos %}
        <li>
            {{ form_label(documento) }}
            {{ form_widget(documento) }}
            <a href="#" class="remove-item">Eliminar</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FormType**

In your case we need to create formType for `PersonaDocumento`. Imagine, that this entity has field documentName:

```
class PersonaDocumentoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface  $builder
     * @param array                 $options
     * @SuppressWarnings(unused)
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('documentName', TextType::class, [
                'label'                 => false,
                'translation_domain'    => 'messages'
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_persona_documento_type';
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_persona_documento';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'            => PersonaDocumento::class,
            'csrf_protection'       => true,
            'validation'            => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

**Form that contain collection**

Consider you entity `Formulario`. It has a OneToMany relation to PersonaDocumento. And Form will be:

```
class FormularioFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface  $builder
     * @param array                 $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...

        $builder
            ->add('documentos', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'    => PersonaDocumentoType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label'         => false,
                ],
                'label'         => false,
                'allow_add'     => true,
                'allow_delete'  => true,
                'by_reference'  => false,  // Very important thing!
            ])
        ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Widget for collection**

We have a form (*FormularioFormType*) that contain collection of small forms with type *PersonaDocumentoType*.

New widget you can create in file with standard widgets, and name of the `file is fields.html.twig` : `path_to_your_project/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig`.

Name of the block will be `app_persona_documento_widget`.

Thus, example of `fields.html.twig` :

```
{% trans_default_domain 'messages' %}

{% block app_persona_documento_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-group" {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr' : { 'placeholder' : 'app.form.label.name'|trans , 'class' : 'form-control' }}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock app_persona_documento_widget %}
```

Also pay attention that "app_persona_documento_widget" - assembled from the `getBlockPrefix()` of you PersonaDocumentoType plus string "_widget"

**Register new form themes in config.yml**

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
        # other form themes
        # ...
        - 'AppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

**Render collection in parent form**

```
            {{ form_start(formulario_form) }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        Label
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 documentos" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(formulario_form.documentos.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                        {% for document in formulario_form.documentos %}
                            <div>
                                {{ form_widget(document) }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span>
                    {{ form_errors(formulario_form) }}
                </span>
                {#  Here you can add another fields of form   #}
            {{ form_end(formulario_form) }}
```

Of course, you also need buttons: one *"Add another document"* button and *"Remove"* buttons for each "Documento" item.

Symfony documentation suggests that we use JavaScript for this purpose. 
You can read more [here in official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)

Also you can install [Ninsuo/symfony-collection](https://packagist.org/packages/ninsuo/symfony-collection#2.1.19) - *A jQuery plugin that manages adding, deleting and moving elements from a Symfony collection*

Comment: I would like to know if there are another way, for example : changing something in some fixture in app/config because it is a preconfiguration of symfony. Thanks

Comment: And I don´t want to create this for all the collections and forms in my application

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini, this is the official way. And there aren't any more convenient way to add collections. But!

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini BUT!  you can install bundle for collections - Ninsuo/symfony-collection. You can find it on Packagist. This bundle provides for you navigation buttons (add and remove).

Comment: I have just created the folder 'FORM' in path_to_your_project/src/AppBundle/Resources/views with the .twig inside and i also added the blockPrefix in DocumentoType but is not working and I have no errors and nothing that seems that the code works

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini, I will edit my answer to provide more info

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini can you expose your Entity and Form?

Comment: this is the type: ´->add('documentos', CollectionType::class, array(
                    // each entry in the array will be "document" field
                    'entry_type' => PersonaDocumentoType::class,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    // these options are passed to each "document" type
                    'entry_options' => array('label' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'document-box')
                    ),´

Comment: and the entity : /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonaDocumento", cascade={"persist"},orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $documentos;
     */
    (The entity has get,add and remove methods)

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini  - I forgot to tell that you need to register your new theme in config.yml - watch that in edited answer

Comment: Now I have an error when I acces the route of the form, "Unable to find template "AppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig" (looked into: E:\sympony-projects\fluo\app/Resources/views, E:\sympony-projects\fluo\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form)"

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini then try to move `Form/fields.html.twig` to `app/Resources/views`

Comment: I have just moved the folder and the error continues

Comment: @LucasLeonelAzzollini Did you registered new theme and config.yml and  cleared the cache?

Comment: yes I put the configuration you mencioned in config.yml, then I moved the twig to several paths and finally I cleared the cache to start the serve and the error continues

Comment: I solved the problem including form_theme in the twig

Comment: con you help me with this issue ? ir is very frustrating [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086257/symfony3-how-to-persist-an-object-with-its-collections/48098465?noredirect=1#comment83235243_48098465]